# How to use an Observer() function instead of a loop

Tags: javascript, repeat, repeater, observers

I am requesting help as no matter how many tutorials I watch, I cannot seem to figure out how use the `Observer()` function to get it to replace a link with another only if that link appears.
Am I misunderstanding the `Observer()` function?

This is my current code:

```
    function loop(){
        
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="https://media.app.net/attachments"]');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.src = image.src.replace('https://media.app.net/attachments', 'https://cdn.app.com/attachments');
});

    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}
```

I was told that I could make my code a lot less resource hungry by using an `Observer()` function and I would really like to achieve this, but obviously I can't. I want to learn.

Comment: Which "*`Observer()` function*" do you refer to? Please share links to those tutorials you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` to listen for new elements being added. To improve performance, do not observe the entire `document`; instead, choose the closest static ancestor that will contain all the dynamically added `<img>` elements.

Example:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations)
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node?.matches?.('img[src^="https://media.app.net/attachments"]')) {
        console.log('original src', node.src);
        node.src = node.src.replace('https://media.app.net/attachments', 'https://cdn.app.com/attachments');
        console.log('updated src:', node.src);
      }
    }
});
observer.observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://media.app.net/attachments/' + Math.random();
  document.body.append(img);
});
```

```html
<button>Add img</button>
```